# Workbox 3: Is it possible to change the response's HTML before returning it?

Tags: service-worker, workbox

Users can choose to use a dark theme, that will add a "dark-theme" class to the BODY element.

The problem is that pages will be cached with that class present and if the user disables the dark theme, cached pages still return with the dark-theme class.

Is it possible to strip that class from cached pages just before Workbox sends the cached page back to the browser?

I'm checking if the right theme is applied when the DOM is ready, if not it will strip or add the "dark-theme" class. That change is visible to the user, so I'm looking for another solution. Unfortunately I can't use Ajax to fetch the page and update just the content.

I'm using Workbox 3.6.1. This is the relevant code on my service-worker.js

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
        new RegExp('/article/'),
        async ({
            event
        }) => {
            try {
                return await workbox.strategies.networkFirst({
                    cacheName: 'articles'
                }).handle({
                    event
                });
            } catch (error) {
                return caches.match(OFFLINE_PAGE);
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: What is your cache strategy ?
Can you please show us some of your code ? It will be easier to help you then.

Comment: I added the relevant code requested. I'm using networkFirst(). I feel that I should be able to use handle() to modify the response before sending it to the browser, but I can't find more details about that.

Comment: I don't know any built-in way in workbox to alter responses from the Routing API using default strategies.

I think the easiest work-around is to use the "Stale While Revalidate" strategy and manage the dark/light-theme in your webapp.

Otherwise, you can implement your own strategy with a custom Handler callback like explicated here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-routing#matching_and_handling_in_routes